# How to bypass a $filter in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a newcomer in the field of MongoDB. I have a long aggregation pipeline query string inside which I have a portion like this under $project,

```js
...
...
productType: {
                  $filter: {
                       input: "$productTypes",
                       as: "productType",
                       cond: {
                                $eq: ["$$productType", projectConditions['productType']]
                            }
                       }
              }
...
..
```

Basically that `productType` is coming from API requests as a query parameter. But, this filter is completely optional.

I want to make this query string flexible such that if anything comes as `productType` it will be taken as a filter condition, if nothing comes from API, I want to bypass this filter so that every productType can be considered.

```js
[
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 1,
                    methodNo: 1,
                    methodStatus: 1,
                    category: 1,
                    productType: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$productTypes",
                            as: "productType",
                            cond: {
                                $eq: ["$$productType", projectConditions['productType']]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    methodType: 1,
                    documentType: 1,
                    locations: 1,
                    methodDocuments: {
                        $map: {
                            input: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: "$methodDocuments",
                                    as: "methodDocument",
                                    cond: {
                                        $eq: ["$$methodDocument.lang", projectConditions['lang']]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            as: "methodDocument",
                            in: {
                                methodTitle: "$$methodDocument.methodTitle",
                                lang: "$$methodDocument.lang",
                                versions: {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: "$$methodDocument.versions",
                                        as: "versionItem",
                                        cond: {
                                            $and: [
                                                { $eq: ["$$versionItem.version", projectConditions['version']] },
                                                { $eq: ["$$versionItem.status", projectConditions['status']] },
                                                { $lte: ["$$versionItem.issueDate", projectConditions['issueDateEnd']] },
                                                { $gte: ["$$versionItem.issueDate", projectConditions['issueDateStart']] }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    relatedMethodsLink: 1,
                    attachments: 1,
                    access: 1,
                    createdTime: 1,
                    updatedTime: 1
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $anyElementTrue: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$productType",
                                in: {
                                    $gt: [{ $size: "$$this" }, 0]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    $expr: {
                        $anyElementTrue: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$methodDocuments",
                                in: {
                                    $gt: [{ $size: "$$this" }, 0]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    $expr: {
                        $anyElementTrue: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$methodDocuments",
                                in: {
                                    $gt: [{ $size: "$$this.versions" }, 0]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

This is the whole project pipeline. I am stuck with this. Any suggestion will be helpful to me.

Comment: why dont you use  `$cond` to filter

Comment: @varman can you give me an example?

Comment: Something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Y59Xwlvb4_ this. Condition inside filter condition. `If name="Test" then get related documents else get all documents` . This may not sync with your scenario. But you can get some idea